# React-Native (CRNA) Packager stops running

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, packager

I'm working on a react native app built with CRNA.
Everything was working fine until yesterday. Everytime I run the packager with
`npm start` I get this:

```
Error starting packager: Error: Could not access packager status at http://localhost:19001/status. Are you sure the packager is running and reachable?
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\xdl@50.8.0\src\Project.js:1350:11)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
```

While running the packager I tried to reach the address through my browser and it seems to work for a while (it says the packager is currently running), but suddenly stops working and the packager throws me the error above.
I tried to run `npm install` and checked my package.json but I can't find anything helpful to solve it.
I also tried with a different network, same error.
Could it be a typo in my code that makes the packager go crazy or I have to check something else?

Answer (score 0):

There is an open bug on [expo-cli](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/38) GitHub. I believe need to wait until the bug is resolved.

I am too facing the same issue and for a moment I am using [Snack Expo](https://snack.expo.io) to work on the same machine as of now.

Hope this helps!